# JQuery blockUI and ASP.Net?

Tags: jquery, asp.net

Well im using jQuery and blockUI in asp.net i love jquery and blockUI but i found a problem when displaying a panel with a asp.net button in them the actual button is moved out of the **form** tag, so when you click the button nothing happens..

is there any way to configure blockUI to place its content tags last in the forms tag instead in the body tag!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Now im not 100% sure this is the best solution but i did go into the jquery.blockUI.js and replaced a few lines..

Replace this line

```
var layers = [lyr1, lyr2, lyr3], $par = full ? $('body') : $(el);
```

with

```
var layers = [lyr1, lyr2, lyr3], $par = full ? $('form') : $(el);
```

Replace this line

```
$('html,body').css('height', '100%');
```

with

```
$('html,body,form').css('height', '100%');
```

Replace this line

```
els = $('body').children().filter('.blockUI').add('body > .blockUI');
```

with

```
els = $('form').children().filter('.blockUI').add('body > form > .blockUI');
```

and it seems to be working so far haven't tested more than one browser yet!!

Comment: @Emin well im glad i could be of assistance, i can't say i like the solution but its at least a solution.

Comment: Believe it or not, this also solves some other positioning problems of the modal window where I had to manually overrride some CSS properties to overcome the situation. It is a very simple and clever solution that solves the problem down at its roots! I do appreciate it..

Comment: This worked great in Chrome but I couldn't get it to work in IE. Thanks for the answer though!

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you're looking to block just the form when a button is clicked outside the form.  If that's the case BlockUI supports element level blocking like this:

```
$('#blockButton').click(function() { 
   $('form').block({ message: null }); 
});
```

Comment: sorry but thats not the problem the problem is that my button is moved outside the form tag, and asp.net requires it to be inside...