# Drop Down List not triggering Index changed event

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net, ajax

My drop down list triggers code behind on index change when I use this,

```
$('#messagebox').show();
```

but NOT triggering event when I use,

```
 $.blockUI({message: $('#messagebox'), css: { width: '600px' } });
```

Here's my markup for div where drop down is, appears like a message box

```
<div id="messagebox" style="display: none; cursor: default">
   <asp:DropDownList ID="ddl" runat="server" EnableViewState="true" AutoPostBack="true" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddl_SelectedIndexChanged"/>
</div>
```

How can I solve this issue ?

Comment: Where exactly you are putting this jquery can you please share some more code detail?

Comment: what code you need ? its a plugin I am using , here http://www.malsup.com/jquery/block/

Comment: Try setting the focus to the messagebox after you show it. `$('#messagebox').focus();`

Comment: Why you are using Jquery to show Dropdown?

Comment: Because I want to sir ?

Comment: Didn't get you, when you block the UI how do you change/select the dropdown ?

Comment: @V4Vendetta I would recommend you try BlockUI live demo please :)

Comment: @Ignacio What i meant is `.Show()` serves a different purpose it shows your `dropdown` while the block part when is it done or called, found that part confusing ... :(

Comment: Have u placed your div in update panel?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is most likely because blockUI is appending the content to the body, instead of to the form tag.  Asp.Net controls will not post back events if they are outside of the form tag, so you run into it often when appending elements to the body with javascript.  You will most likely have to make a couple of amendments to BlockUI.

For more info, see this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7929700/1346464.

**Edit:**

Summarising the linked answer (based on blockUI v2.59.0-2013.04.05, which is the latest at time of writing):

On line 319 (search for `var layers`), replace `$('body')` with `$('form')`.

On line 336 (search for `$('html,body').css('height','100%');`), replace `$('html,body')` with `$('html,body,form')`.

**Edit 2:**

Fixes unblocking:

On line 448 (search for `els = $('body').children().filter('.blockUI').add('body > .blockUI');`) replace both instances of `body` with `form`.

Comment: I edited your answer on other post, as it wasn't making sense , tell me if it's right please

Comment: oh sorry, maybe I can't edit it, but he is saying too many "with" and also I only find first line

Comment: I fixed it by changing first line only, you are a genius and life saver for finding that, thanks

Comment: No problem, this kind of thing has stumped me several times.  Updated my answer with the locations of both lines.

Comment: Updated my answer again to fix unblocking.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with jQuery blockUI, but with jQuery Dialog, it removes any form fields from the form when it is displayed.  Therefore, when the form is posted back, you don't have access to them.

With jQuery Dialog, you have to add some code to get the fields added back to the form.  I'd recommend searching to see if blockUI has the same issue.

Answer (score -3):

```
autopostbackproperty=true like  below

<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlName"  runat="server" AutoPostBack ="true"
    onselectedindexchanged="ddlName_SelectedIndexChanged" >
</asp:DropDownList>

protected void ddlName_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

}
```